# Complicated Cython embedded executable with f2py compiled module

Tags: python, embed, cython, f2py

I am trying to cythonize a python project found at https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/phaseshifts/phaseshifts-0.1.2-dev.zip with the end goal of creating a standalone executable for the phsh.py module. The core structure of the project I wish to embed has the following hierarchy:

```
phaseshifts/
    __init__.py
    atorb.py
    conphas.py
    elements.py
    leed.py
    phsh.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        libphsh.pyd`
```

Note: The `libphsh.pyd` module is compiled using `f2py`.

I guess my question is really split into multiple parts:

**1)** How can you use `cython` to create a standalone executable containing multiple `.py[x]?` files? (like when using the `--embed` option for a single module to embed the python interpreter)
**2)** If 1) is possible, then can compiled `.pyd` or `.so` files be included and if so how?

Any help from the SO veterans would be most appreciated :-)

### Edit

A crude work-around has so far involved compiling `libphsh.f` into a dll using `gfortran -shared -o libphsh.dll libphsh.f` then editing the relevant source files to load the library using [ctypes](http://jjd-comp.che.wisc.edu/index.php/PythonCtypesTutorial). Next I used `cython *.py` to create C source files of each python module I desire, except for phsh.py, where I used `cython --embed phsh.py`.

Finally I used GCC to compile the source and link to the python library, e.g.

```
gcc -o phsh.exe phsh.c __init__.c atorb.c conphas.c elements.c leed.c model.c \
-I"C:\Python27\include" -L"C:\Python27\libs" -lpython27
```

However upon running the compiled executable the app terminates displaying the message:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

### Edit 2

The unusual termination can be avoided using `g++` to compile the cpp souce file generated from:

```
cython --cplus --embed phsh.py
```

In fact the points listed in the first edit are both a lot of effort and do not work as the compiled executable still tries to import each python module, so each module could perhaps be compiled too, but the most important step is to compile `libphsh.f`:

```
f2py -m libphsh libphsh.f
```

The next stage is to try to automate this with a setup script...